# Localisation : Load translation file dynamically

Tags: spring-boot, localization, internationalization, locale, translation

I am developing a Spring Boot Application to localize the data. I am able to localize using the translation files.

```java
import java.util.Locale;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver;

@Configuration
public class LocaleConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    /**
     * * @return default Locale set by the user
     */
    @Bean(name = "localeResolver")
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
        return slr;
    }

    /**
     * an interceptor bean that will switch to a new locale based on the value of
     * the language parameter appended to a request:
     *
     * @param registry
     * @language should be the name of the request param
     *           <p>
     *           Note: All requests to the backend needing Internationalization
     *           should have the "lang" request param
     */
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor);
    }


}
```

In my src/main/resource folder, I am keeping my translation keys.

> messages_en.properties
>
> message_fr.properties

Now using message source, I am able to translate the data

```java
String translatedMessage = messageSource.getMessage(key, null, "default_message",
                    LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
```

**WHAT IS THE ISSUE??**

I am using PhraseApp service, and I have to sync translation every time I get a request to translate any data i.e download the translations files at runtime and load it in the Spring boot application.

I am able to update the *messages_en.properties" files and other properties file at run time but not able to load it back. The old translation is active. If I restart the application, new translation became active,

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Adding below bean to LocaleConfiguration should refresh the translations after 60 seconds (which can be changed by passing the desired value. You could also have a refresh interval in milliseconds if required - refer commented line):

```
    @Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
//      messageSource.setCacheMillis(1000);
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(60);
        return messageSource;
    }
```

Comment: I already tried the same. This works if we run on IDE like eclipse. But doesn't work if we run using java -jar abc.war command i.e embedded server case, it doesn't work. The reason : it is reloading resources from bin folder not from resource location

Comment: Tried with file path rather than classpath, which worked from IDE. messageSource.setBasename("file:///Users/atul.kulkarni/locale/messages"); If this works from IDE, it should work as a jar too.

Answer (score 1):

First place your i18n resources in the specific folder, for example in `i18n` inside your project root (but not in the folder `src/main/resources`).

Then add the following bean to your application:

```java
    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource commands = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        commands.setBasename("file:i18n/messages");
        commands.setCacheSeconds(60);
        return commands;
    }
```

Every minute Spring will be evicting the `MessageSource` cache and your application will be able to reread updated data from the `i18n` folder.

Comment: How does it help? Because I am creating a war file, so all the resources will be inside war file. What I will be deploying is a war file and that too at different location.